# Getting data from two different monoliths

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices, monolithic

We are developing a feature that will require getting a similar data set from two monolithic applications and displaying it in one application. The monoliths use totally different tech stacks. We are considering defining a set of data and service contracts that will be implemented as microservices exposing the data from the monoliths. Is that a reasonable approach? Are there other design/architectural patterns that better suit our use case?

Comment: This is hard to tell. How do you access the data? What interfaces offer the two monoliths? Are there other constraints?

Answer (score 1):

> Is that a reasonable approach?

If you want to make it to adapt responses from two monoliths to have one unified response, then yes, it is reasonable. As you can reuse this response without worrying what monolith returned answer. And it is similar to [Adapter](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/adapter) pattern.

Otherwise, it is not reasonable as it brings new application which should be maintained.